# Is it possible to generate comments to functions in Template Haskell?

Tags: haskell, comments, template-haskell, generated-code

In our project we have a lot of TH-generated functions. It'd make sense to add generic comments to them so that they are visible in Haddock/Hoogle. At the very least, something like "This has been generated by TH." Is something like that possible?

Comment: Looks related to [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5467) GHC ticket.

Comment: It must be possible because in my own project, Haddock extracts _some_ documentation from TH code.  See https://github.com/mounty1/JackRose/blob/master/source/Foundation.hs and http://landcroft.com/jackrose/documentation/Foundation.html -- some of those **instance**s have come from my code, but most, not.

Answer (score 2):

This would be nice to have but it isn't currently possible in GHC.